# Email verification in Jsp Spring mvc2

Tags: java, spring, jsp, email, verification

I've been working to make email verification in spring. Now I am just stuck in one spot and don't know exactly which part should I have to fix. Right now email function does not work. 
What I wanted to do was when user typed there email and hit the button, than it automatically create unique verification code and it sent to the e-mail address that was typed by user. when user type the right code in the input than this email address verified successfully and they can create new account.

Here is my Controller

```
//email verification mapping
@RequestMapping(value =  "/emailAutho.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView emailAuth(HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{

    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String authNum = "";

    authNum = RandomNum();

    sendEmail(email.toString(), authNum);

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("/member/emailAuth.jsp");
    mv.addObject("email",email);
    mv.addObject("authNum", authNum);

    return mv;


}

//creating verification code method
private String RandomNum() {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<=6; i++){
            int n = (int) (Math.random() *10);
            buffer.append(n);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

//sending email
private void sendEmail(String email, String authNum) {
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String subjet = "title";
    String fromName = "nomad";
    String from = "";
    String tol = email;

    String content = "your verification number is [" +authNum +"]";

    try{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new Authenticator(){
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                return new PasswordAuthentication("", "", "");

            }
        });

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from, MimeUtility.encodeText(fromName, "UTF-8", "B")));

    InternetAddress[] address1 = {new InternetAddress(tol)};
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address1);
    msg.setSubject(subjet);
    msg.setSentDate(new java.util.Date());
    msg.setContent(content, "text/html;charset=euc-kr"); //set content
    Transport.send(msg);
    }catch(MessagingException e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is javascript to check verification code.

```
    /*check email verification code  */
    function check(){
        var form = document.authenform;
        var authNum = ${authNum};

        if(!form.authnum.value){
            alert("type your verification code");
            return false;
            }
        if(form.authnum.value != authNum){
            alert("This is wrong verification code. Please re-enter the code again.");
            form.authnum.value="";
            return false;
        }
        if(form.authNum.value == authNum){
            alert("verification succeded");
            opener.document.userinput.mailCheck.value="verification succeded.";
            self.close();
        }
    }
```

This is jsp for verification code.

```
<form method="post" name="authenform" onSubmit="return check();">
            <label id="valid_email">Type your 7 digit code.</label>
            <input id="authnum" name="authnum" type="text"/>                        
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

This is jsp for where user type their email address and hit the button than send verification code.

```
<form method="post" name="emailAutho" onSubmit="return check();">
            <label id="valid_email">email</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="email" />                      
            <input type="submit" class="form-style-join" value="submit">
```

The problem is email does not sent, just shows error message 500 
 Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`

Comment: What exactly does not work? Which part of code causes problems? It'd be helpful if you posted stack trace, too.

Comment: @Piotr Podraza Hello, I added what exactly does not work. When I hit the button it supposed to send email with verification code but instead it gives me error message 500 `nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: null`.